# Parallel of std::reference_wrapper for std::shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdbind

If you want to bind a reference to a function `f`, you can use `std::bind(f, std::ref(x))`. In this case `f` takes a reference or makes a copy.

Now I have a function `void g(T & t)`. I would like to bind the input argument to `std::shared_ptr<T> mySharedPtr` like this: `std::bind(g, mySharedPtr)`. This would guarantee that `mySharedPtr`'s data would have a lifetime at least as long as the bind. But since `g` takes a reference, this does not type-check.

**Is there something similar to `std::ref` that takes a `std::shared_ptr` and dereferences it before passing it into `g`? If not, could I make one myself?**

(If you give an answer using lambdas, please also include one without lambdas since my compiler does not support them.)

Edit: `std::bind(g, std::ref(*mySharedPtr))` does not work since it loses the lifetime guarantee of the `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: C++11?  Would wrapping `g` be ok?

Comment: Wrapping `g` would certainly work if I had lambdas. Unfortunately I don't, so I would have to manually wrap each `g`-like function before binding on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you could create a `deref()` function which would create an object dereferencing something looking like a pointer upon conversion:

```
template <typename P>
class pointer_wrapper {
    P ptr;
public:
    pointer_wrapper(P p): ptr(p) {}
    operator decltype(*std::declval<P>())&() {
        return *ptr;
    }
};
template <typename P>
pointer_wrapper<P> deref(P p) {
    return p;
}
```

It may be better to make the conversion a member template to allow a few more conversions.